# Extracting Complete Ship Passenger List

Tags: immigration, manifest

I am looking for the full ship record (Ellis Island, ship = Calabria, Arrival date IV.06.1911). Here is a sample : https://www.dropbox.com/s/94pj3l3nc5tusi4/1911%204%2022%20Leonidas%20Zoto%202.jpg?dl=0
Is there a way to access it in a smart way or do I have to go page by page?

Ideally, I would like both the transcript of the full record and a copy of all scanned pages.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Are you talking about collecting all the images for that arrival date, making a transcription of all the passengers on board, both, or something else?

Comment: Both, ideally. In the WCS, one of the two.

Comment: Just FYI, I'm interpreting what I'm finding as that the ship sailed from Naples on 6 April 1911, from Palermo on 7 April 1911, and arrived at Ellis Island on 22 April 1911. What you're showing is the record of sailing from Naples, not the records of arrival at Ellis Island.

Comment: What have you tried, and why is it unsuitable?

Comment: I have to download the record page by page, but it is very fastidious.